# Formatting text using `...` only in one specific environment

Tags: formatting, environments

I would like to make the character `` ` ``  active in one environment so that `` `some text` `` will be formatted using black background and white for the text.

This feature must be activated only inside the environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `` ` `` active and read everything up to the next `` ` ``. The colors can be set using `\colorbox` and `\textcolor` from the `xcolor` package.

You might also want to compensate for the added left/right space as shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\catcode96=\active
\newenvironment{myenv}{%
    \catcode96=\active% ASCII ` = 96
    \def`##1`{%
        \hspace{-\fboxsep}%
        \colorbox{black}{\textcolor{white}{##1}}%
        \hspace{-\fboxsep}%
    }%
}{%
}
\catcode96=12

\begin{document}

`text`

\begin{myenv}
    text text text

    text `text` text
\end{myenv}

`text`

\end{document}
```

With the `\hspace`s you get:

[image: Result with \hspace's]

Without you get:

[image: Result without \hspace's]

You could also just take half the `\fboxsep` away to get an intermediate result.